# Google Analytic Real-Time Overview not Responding?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

My page Analytic sudden show this message on Real-Time Overview Page. What does that mean? How it's occurred. Need a Solution? 
[image]

Comment: It sounds like a problem on Google's end to me or possibly a connection error between you and Google.   If you try again today, is the problem gone?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
After 20 minutes later, it's get back to the position Autometically. Almost two weeks ago the same problem also happened. Want to know why this problem occur. Is this a sign of big error? I am afraid for this actually..